# What Sanitize modules are for?

Tags: angularjs, sanitize, html-sanitizing, sanitization

I'm looking for this *new* concept (for me) of **Sanitize** the HTML,
 I've read all about what this module does, but I really don't understand **what's that for**, and **where use it**, and **what this can contribute** for my future projects.

If some of you want to read about that > [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)

p.s: I just want a practical answer nothing too long.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the sanitize module ensures that when you have variables which contain HTML content, that content is "safe", and won't cause unexpected side effects.  This could be anything from SQL injection to executing javascript functions, site redirections, link replacements, etc.

Comment: that was really ojective, can you make an answer with some real case scenario? if you wish.

Comment: I can't really make it any clearer than the examples on the documentation page you posted in the question already do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app accepts input that is to be compiled as HTML - you would use the `$sanitize` service to ensure that the accepted inputs are free from  attempts to inject malicious code.

Comment: like sql injection? this sanitization avoid these scenarios?

Comment: while you can sanitize inputs on the front end to avoid sql injection - the safest thing you do can would be to add parameterization on the backend.  see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)

Comment: That was really helpful! Can you tell some example in practice?

Comment: I assume you mean of sql injection. In the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) I posted above, they gave the example `';DROP TABLE bar;--`

Comment: I'd say that its use is highly situational - an example might be if i were to write an email app that allowed users to create a custom signature field - I might want to sanitize the inputted HTML to ensure that it wasn't malicious in order to protect other users from a feature that my app exposes.